# Dividing each row of an xts or zoo time series object by a fixed row

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I am trying to divide an xts object which holds a number of time series (columns; with a common date column (index). I want to divide each column by its value at a specified date (say '2010-09-30'). This is so as to re-scale the entire object with values of 1 in each column at that date (a common re-basing task). Had it been an ordinary matrix, `A`, and the row I wanted to rebase to was say `A[6,]`, I could just do

```
t(t(A)/A[6,])
```

and that works. But, trying to manipulate the xts object and its row subset `xts['2010-09-30']` doesn't work as easily. Could someone please point me in the right direction. I realise this is very basic and I should have found the answer on my own. In fact, if there is a better method in general for rebasing time series in this manner using a package, I am happy to adopt that approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xts and zoo objects are aligned by index before operations.  If you want to divide an entire object by a value at a single row, you have to use `coredata` (and maybe `drop`) to get the value to an atomic vector (with only one element).

For example:

```
library(xts)
x <- xts(1:10,as.Date("2011-12-21")+1:10)
x / drop(coredata(x['2011-12-26']))
```

Comment: Many thanks @Joshua as usual. I will now try this. BTW, any suggestion on my query yesterday on that data merge operation using quantmod? If it’s a real problem, I'll look in other directions....I just want to make sure its not a beginner error on my part....

Comment: Absolutely worked! Thanks again. I had used coredata a lot recently....don't know how I forgot that...:)