# how to read time series in xts?

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have this time series data:

```
     "timestamp"          "depth" "from_sensor_to_river_bottom" "Depth_from_river_surface_to_bottom"
"1" "2012-05-23 18:30:12-05" 16.4 17.16 0.760000000000002
"2" "2012-05-23 18:15:08-05" 16.38 17.16 0.780000000000001
"3" "2012-05-23 18:00:03-05" 16.39 17.16 0.77
"4" "2012-05-23 17:45:13-05" 16.35 17.16 0.809999999999999
"5" "2012-05-23 17:30:08-05" 16.37 17.16 0.789999999999999
```

I am using the following code:

```
d <- read.table(Name[1], header=TRUE)  #Name[1] is text file containing data

d <- read.zoo(d,
 format="'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'", 
 FUN=as.POSIXct  )
```

Its giving me this error:

```
Error in read.zoo(d, format = "'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'", FUN = as.POSIXct) : 
 index has 5 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5
```

I wish to get help on this problem. 
Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: what are the "-05" bits at the end of your times?

Comment: @BenBolker Precisely. That's what's causing the problem, since `as.POSIXct` doesn't know how to deal with this.

Comment: @BenBolker It seems to be a badly formatted time stamp. See my answer.

Comment: I don't know what it is. It came along, when I got the data from internet.
can we deal with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on the data in the post provided its OK to ignore the `-05` at the end of each date/time.  (To read from a file use something like the commented out line.)

```
Lines <- '"timestamp"          "depth" "from_sensor_to_river_bottom" "Depth_from_river_surface_to_bottom"
"1" "2012-05-23 18:30:12-05" 16.4 17.16 0.760000000000002
"2" "2012-05-23 18:15:08-05" 16.38 17.16 0.780000000000001
"3" "2012-05-23 18:00:03-05" 16.39 17.16 0.77
"4" "2012-05-23 17:45:13-05" 16.35 17.16 0.809999999999999
"5" "2012-05-23 17:30:08-05" 16.37 17.16 0.789999999999999'

library(zoo)
# z <- read.zoo("myfile.txt", tz = "")
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, tz = "")
```

The output from the above code is:

```
> z
                    depth from_sensor_to_river_bottom Depth_from_river_surface_to_bottom
2012-05-23 17:30:08 16.37                       17.16                               0.79
2012-05-23 17:45:13 16.35                       17.16                               0.81
2012-05-23 18:00:03 16.39                       17.16                               0.77
2012-05-23 18:15:08 16.38                       17.16                               0.78
2012-05-23 18:30:12 16.40                       17.16                               0.76
```

For more info try [?read.zoo](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/zoo/html/read.zoo.html) and [?read.table](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/utils/html/read.table.html) and also [vignette("zoo-read")](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-read.pdf).  The last one is an entire document focused on giving `read.zoo` examples.

EDIT: Added links to commentary.

Answer (score 4):

Your timestamp data contains badly formatted timezone data, i.e. those `-05` endings to each timestamp.

From `?strptime` I learn that you can use `%z` to format a signed timezone offset, which should be a signed four-digit number, e.g. `-0500`.

```
%z
Signed offset in hours and minutes from UTC, so -0800 is 8 hours behind UTC.
```

So, here is a workaround that adds the missing `00` to your timestamps:

Recreate your data:

```
dat <- '
"timestamp" "depth" "from_sensor_to_river_bottom" "Depth_from_river_surface_to_bottom"
"1" "2012-05-23 18:30:12-05" 16.4 17.16 0.760000000000002
"2" "2012-05-23 18:15:08-05" 16.38 17.16 0.780000000000001
"3" "2012-05-23 18:00:03-05" 16.39 17.16 0.77
"4" "2012-05-23 17:45:13-05" 16.35 17.16 0.809999999999999
"5" "2012-05-23 17:30:08-05" 16.37 17.16 0.789999999999999
'
```

Add the missing zeroes:

```
x <- read.table(text=dat, header=TRUE)
x$timestamp <- paste(x$timestamp, "00", sep="")
x$timestamp <- as.POSIXct(x$timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
x
```

Convert to zoo

```
library(zoo)
as.zoo(x)
  timestamp           depth from_sensor_to_river_bottom Depth_from_river_surface_to_bottom
1 2012-05-24 00:30:12 16.40 17.16                       0.76                              
2 2012-05-24 00:15:08 16.38 17.16                       0.78                              
3 2012-05-24 00:00:03 16.39 17.16                       0.77                              
4 2012-05-23 23:45:13 16.35 17.16                       0.81                              
5 2012-05-23 23:30:08 16.37 17.16                       0.79
```

Comment: but this has changed the time series values:
see values of timestamp in my data and the one you obtained

Comment: I don't think it has. The data indicates a 5 hour offset vs UTC. The zoo object prints the UTC time, which is correct. If you want different behaviour, you can easily use similar logic to remove the `-05` strings from your data display local time.

Comment: Okay..Thank you for that. 
I want to subtract two values of time. I tried doing it using this code and failed. How can it be made possible?

Comment: To add (or subtract) times from `POSIXct` objects, simply add (or subtract) the number of seconds you desire, i.e. `z <- date - seconds`

Comment: Not that way...
after converting it to zoo: i get the dataset x
then I want-> x[2,1] - x[3,1]
and get the answer in hours. Possible? It'd be of great help

Comment: @rockswap: that's a different question; and I have already answered it on [Dividing each row of an xts or zoo time series object by a fixed row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595053/dividing-each-row-of-an-xts-or-zoo-time-series-object-by-a-fixed-row) and [zoo/xts - can't do math on 1-cell subsets? R hangs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516006/zoo-xts-cant-do-math-on-1-cell-subsets-r-hangs).