# Creating Loop to indexing values in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, indexing, na

I downloaded several timeseries via Yahoo-Finance, Reuters and other sources.

They are all listed as seperate "xts"-objects which contains the respective closing price. These vectors are available for daily and monthly intervals.

I would like to create one chart which shows the price developement of my stocks.
This chart should the relative price developement in relation to the first day:

```
price of 2005-01-04/price of 2005-01-03 
price of 2005-01-05/price of 2005-01-03
```

and so on.

For this I tried to create a for-loop:

```
indexfun <- function(x)
  {
  y <- as.matrix(x)
  z <- rep(NULL, nrow(x))
  for(i in nrow(y)){
  z[i] <- y[i,1]/y[1,1]
    print(z)
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it returns soley NA-values except for the last one.
I tried to save the vector as matrix to ensure I can acces the column containing the closing prices and leaving the dates untouched.

My xts-vector looks like

```
           BA.close
2005-01-03    50.97
2005-01-04    49.98
2005-01-05    50.81
2005-01-06    50.48
2005-01-07    50.31
2005-01-10    50.98
```

Can you help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try `for(i in 1:nrow(y))`.

Comment: Unfortunately it delivers the same result (NA values).

Comment: Can you share your data with the `dput()` function (or just a sample)?

Comment: @Lyngbakr this doesn't do anything

Comment: @Mike https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/768558/bdaily.csv
It is basically just the closing returns of Boeing, downloaded from Yahoo (symbol: "BA").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dividing each row of an xts or zoo time series object by a fixed row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595053/dividing-each-row-of-an-xts-or-zoo-time-series-object-by-a-fixed-row)

Comment: @AndreElrico My point was that the loop in the question was just running for one iteration – that is, `i` equal to `nrow(y)`. I assumed the OP wanted the loop to over all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution that works for `xts`:

```
library(xts)

x <- xts(c(50.97, 49.98, 50.81, 50.48, 50.31, 50.98),as.Date("2005-01-03")+0:5)

x / drop(coredata(x['2005-01-03']))


                [,1]
2005-01-03 1.0000000
2005-01-04 0.9805768
2005-01-05 0.9968609
2005-01-06 0.9903865
2005-01-07 0.9870512
2005-01-08 1.0001962
```

---

If you have more columns where each is a different stock, and you want to divide by the same date:

first convert to `matrix` your data and remove the date column (you'll put it back later), keep in mind that we use the first row to divide.

```
mat <- as.matrix(d[,-1]) # remove the dates

sweep(mat,2,mat[1, ],`/`) # divide by mat[1, ]. i.e. first row
#            aaa      bbb
# [1,] 1.0000000 1.000000
# [2,] 0.9805768 2.090909
# [3,] 0.9968609 4.090909
# [4,] 0.9903865 5.090909
# [5,] 0.9870512 7.818182
# [6,] 1.0001962 3.090909
# now we can trasform back to data.frame and cbind() with the dates.
```

Data used:

```
tt <- "date     aaa     bbb
2005-01-03    50.97     11
2005-01-04    49.98     23
2005-01-05    50.81     45
2005-01-06    50.48     56
2005-01-07    50.31     86
2005-01-10    50.98     34"

d <- read.table(text=tt, header=T)
```

Comment: Every stock has its single close price vector, formated as xts.

Comment: Your first approach delivers:
> index_boeing_daily<- for (i in seq_along(1:nrow(ts_boeing_daily))) {
+   ts_boeing_daily$new[i] <- ts_boeing_daily[i, "BA.close"] / ts_boeing_daily[1, "BA.close"] # note the 1 to stick to the first date
+ }
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

The for-loop:
> ts_boeing_daily %>% 
+   mutate(new = BA.close/ts_boeing_daily$BA.close[date=="2005-01-03"])
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('xts', 'zoo')"

Comment: Sorry about that, now I've updated with a solution for `xts` objects.

Comment: Thank you very much!! You made my day :). Thanks.